# How to swap bullets with chickens

Tags: crysis-warhead

I discovered that pirated versions of the game make all guns [shoot chickens instead of bullets](http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/1vd0u9/til_that_if_you_illegally_download_crysis_warhead/).

Rather then trying to pirate anything, is there any way to turn this on with a legit copy of the game?

Comment: What's not to like about this! :D

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no possible way. Developers made this "glitch" so people who downloaded this game illegally off the internet would shoot chickens instead of bullets. They did this because it would make the game almost impossible for people who downloaded it illegally.